# Chess Game WPF MouseDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a chess game with wpf and I have never used wpf before. I've used windows forms, so besides the xaml, it's pretty familiar. Usually when I want to create a mousedown event I look at what I have on window design screen->click the object->go to properties->events->MouseDown event->double click the event->it creates a method that executes when the mouse is pressed on that element. Looks like this...

```
private void Pawn_1__MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

But for my chess game in my C# code in the mainwindow constructor I put some initialization code to place a bunch of rectangles all over the screen representing the grid I'd be using for my chess game. How can I create a MouseDown event for these rectangles since they aren't in the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using System.Draw methods to draw the rectangles (I hope you are not drawing labels or something cause that would kill performance). I would make a mouse down event on the form, and then use the mouse position value to get the rectangle that was clicked depending on the width/height of them.

So say the user clicks at 250,250 and the rectangles are 100x100, then he clicked the rectangle[(int) mouse.X / 100, (int) mouse.Y / 100], which is rectangle[2,2] (third row third column). That way you can access the clicked rectangle and handle it the way you are supposed to.

Comment: I have a Canvas set up and I just add them to the Canvas using canvasnamehere.children.Add(objhere);

Comment: @AndrewWilson So I suppose my answer would work ? or you were looking for something else ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I didn't think of that. -.-

Comment: @AndrewWilson you could use this logic for any shape as well, using a list of shapes, setting each shape's properties and using the proper geometry. here the position of the rectangle is granted because it is a chess game and each rectangle is strictly next to each other, but you get the idea